# How to use a filter in javascript instead of the Html

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and it's great. 
I can't find it in the Documentation - What is the equivalent in Javascript to this AngularJS expression:

```
<div>{{ (myList| filter:mySearch).length }}</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use filter in controller in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-filter-in-controller-in-angularjs)

Comment: You are correct, I didn't search enough. It's the same thing, sorry for duplicating.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's on Angular's [filter documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter):

### In HTML Template Binding

> {{ filter_expression | filter:expression }}

### In JavaScript

> $filter('filter')(array, expression)

In your case, it would look something like `$filter('filter')(myList, mySearch)`.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I thought to do, but I had a problem with $filter being "not defined". I didn't include it.. Now it's included and this is working. Thanks!

Comment: What does the string 'filter' do?

Comment: Ditto -- what's the purpose of `'filter'` in the first link of the Curry-chain?

Comment: @Cody `$filter('filter')` returns the filter function, where `'filter'` refers to the name of the filter you want. In this case, since it is a generic filter, Angular team simply decided to named it `'filter'`.

Comment: You can use `$filter` to use AngularJS filter function on arrays from within your javascript code. Say you want to sort an array of objects on a property `sum`. You could do that like this: `$filter('orderBy')(myArr, "sum", false)` - which is the same as doing it in a `ng-repeat`like this: `ng-repeat="t in myArr | orderBy:'sum':false"`.
So if somewhere in your code you need to get a version of your array sorted as in the `ng-repeat` this is handy.
Please remember that it will only work on a `scope`. I use to store my `$scope` in a global `$gs`. Makes testing easier: `$gs.$filter...`

Comment: I'm getting `_co.$filter is not a function`.

Comment: Anyone know how do exactly that with the Fuzzy code? https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#fuzzy

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative syntax you can also inject a filter directly, without going through the `$filter` service. For example to inject `filter` filter to your controller you could write:

```
MyCtrl = function($scope, filterFilter) {

  $scope.filtered = filterFilter(myArray, expression);
}
```

A question very similar to [How to use a filter in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14302267/1418796)

Answer (score 2):

In your html

```
<input ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter:searchResults"></div>
```

In your JS

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  var searchResults = filterFilter($scope.things, $scope.search);
});
```

Comment: Do you know how do exactly that with the Fuzzy code? github.com/a8m/angular-filter#fuzzy