# How do I return a count in Angular for the number of divs on my page with specific values or properties?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I am working with dynamic web, this connected to websocket, then when my web load, i call a load.php (with angular directive).

This web(load.php) makes a `select` in mySQL (i have many tables, linked when id).

Then I make a left join in all tables and I get a unidimensinal array with info about all tables.

Next i show all data with angularjs, each table in different div, where if `TABLEX_VALUE!='null'` -->ng-show, eq:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in alldata">
       <div ng-show="TABLEX_VALUE!='null'">
           {{data.TABLEX_VALUE1}}  - {{data.TABLEX_VALUE2}}
      </div>
     <div ng-show="TABLEY_VALUE!='null'">
           {{data.TABLEY_VALUE1}}  - {{data.TABLEY_VALUE2}}
      </div>
         .
         .
         .
         .
      <div ng-show="TABLEZ_VALUE!='null'">
           {{data.TABLEZ_VALUE1}}  - {{data.TABLEZ_VALUE2}}
      </div>
</div>
```

How do  I count all tables where TABLEX_VALUE!='null'?

Comment: From where `TABLEZ_VALUE` is coming from?

Comment: do you want the div shown after `ng-repeat` rendering completed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$filter` to get all the elements with your desired values, and look for the length of the resulting array.

See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller) [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935996/how-to-use-a-filter-in-javascript-instead-of-the-html) questions, which are related but aren't asking the same thing.

You're looking for the JavaScript pattern:

`$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`