# How to adapt working html Angular filter for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, binding, angularjs-filter

In html, `{{ 'ShowFullMonth' | translate }}` works fine to display some localised text 'Show Full Month'.  However, when studying the [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935996/how-to-use-a-filter-in-javascript-instead-of-the-html) and the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) I cannot see how to adapt this for javascript.

`$filter('translate')(['ShowFullMonth'])` gives me `[object Object]`.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do not pass it as array, use it like this $filter('translate')('ShowFullMonth')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$filter('translate')('ShowFullMonth')
```

Like in your view - you have to pass it a string ;)

Answer (score 2):

Angular filter functions do not expect the arguments to be wrapped up in an Array - just pass them normally.

```
$filter('translate')('ShowFullMonth')
```

If your filter function took multiple arguments, you'd just pass them normally too:

```
$filter('myFilter')(param1, param2, param3)
```

Comment: Thanks but Tomek beat you to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute `$filter` like this:

```
$filter('translate')('ShowFullMonth')
```

instead of:

```
$filter('translate')(['ShowFullMonth'])
```

Because in your view it's a `string` not an `array` object

Comment: Thanks but Tomek beat you to it.