# AngularJS - How to add fuzzy angular-filter

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add the Fuzzy filter following these installation steps

1. [Angular-filter - GetStarted](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#get-started)
2. [Angular-filter fuzzy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#fuzzy).

When I run the app, I get the error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: fuzzyFilterProvider <- fuzzyFilter

- Any help about what I have missed or did wrong please?

or

- Anyone know how do that in a javascript file instead of in the html file?

Here is my code:

**my-component.html**

```
<custom-text name="search" model="list.search"></custom-text>
<li ng-repeat="question in list.questions | fuzzy: list.search">
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.17/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var portal = angular.module('app-portal', ['angular.filter']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**

---

**Solution:**

> I found where add the provider. The provider name is a8m.fuzzy.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Can you show your setup? have you followed all the steps. It's working fine for me after following all the steps mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @palasH I have added the code. Do you know how do it in a javascript file instead of in the html file?

Comment: Sure. Could you please first create a small demo for this using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imhassan66/dEFfK/) that would help us to see what you have missed.

Comment: @palasH sorry but I can't because the data is been taken from a backend. I have found this example in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935996/how-to-use-a-filter-in-javascript-instead-of-the-html and is exactly what I need but using the Fuzzy code.