# Filter inside Template HTML in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to use a filter like a i18n engine, and this filter is working fine. However, if I try to use the i18n filter inside a template HTML (using $routeProvider) I can't do this work.

My Filter:

```
app.filter('i18n', function() {
    return function (input) {
        return $.i18n._(input);
    }
});
```

My HTML template:

```
<div class="fieldConfig first">
                <label id="label_topology" for="topology" class="labelMedio">{{"Topologia" | i18n}}:</label>                    
            </div>
```

My Controller:

```
function WanCtrl($scope, $routParams, $i18n) {
    $scope.title = 'Wan';

};
```

Does I need to put anything more in my controller to work my filter inside the template?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks OK after 3-seconds scanning. Send a plunker with the life code and you will get a response in no time.

Answer (score 0):

To use filters anywhere (controllers, directives, services, etc.) and not just in templates, you need to reference the [`$filter` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$filter). In your case, you're referencing `$i18n` in your controller's parameters which isn't the correct way to go about it.

Instead, pass in `$filter`, and use the `i18n` filter like so:

```js
function WanCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $filter) {
    $scope.title = $filter('i18n')('Wan');
}
```

For more explanation, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302334/586621) on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

A filter like an i18n engine? This is supported in angular-translate! :)

http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/