# Two sets of parentheses after function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was looking how [filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$filter) works in Angularjs and I saw that we need to send 2 sets of parentheses.

```
$filter('number')(number[, fractionSize])
```

What does it means and how do we handle it with JavaScript?

Comment: Personally I find this syntax confusing / awkward to read as well. But you can use simpler syntax to access AngularJS filters as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14303362/1418796

Comment: I took angularjs as an exemple. I wanted to know how to handle this if I create a function myself.

Comment: Actually it's called "currying". a programming technique.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

It means that the first function (`$filter`) returns another function and then that returned  function is called immediately. For Example:

```
function add(x){
  return function(y){
    return x + y;
  };
}

var addTwo = add(2);

addTwo(4) === 6; // true
add(3)(4) === 7; // true
```

Comment: With ES6 arrow functions you could write it the following way:
`let add = (x) => (y) => x + y;`

Comment: Call me a Noob, but please spare your time to explain how can sub-function is able to hold the value of `x`

Comment: @VikasBansal Every time a function is called in Javascript a new execution context is created, as long as there is a reference to another function inside it that execution context will stay in memory.

Comment: if I use `this` to access the variables `x and y` then will it be alright? e.g. `return this.x + this.y` @Paulpro

Comment: @VikasBansal No, only global variables are automatically considered to be properties of an object. `this` always refers to an object, but there is no object that `x` is a property of.

Comment: Why not just pass 2 arguments like `add(x, y)` ? Where is the benefit of calling it like so?

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! Really helped me to understand how passportjs authentication works: `passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, why would I use this ? Real world example anyone?

Comment: Well, the real world example is in OP's question. The $filter service in AngularJS. Here's another example: 

$scope.lowercasehandle = function(){
        return $filter('lowercase')($scope.handle);
    } 
The second argument will be converted to all lowercase.

Comment: A "closure" function as it is now known to be.

Answer (score 28):

`$filter('number')` returns a function that accepts two arguments, the first being required (a number) and the second one being optional (the fraction size).

It's possible to immediately call the returned function:

```
$filter('number')('123')
```

Alternatively, you may keep the returned function for future use:

```
var numberFilter = $filter('number');

numberFilter('123')
```

Comment: this; looks complex: export const toursListQuery = gql`
  query ToursListQuery {
    tours {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(toursListQuery, {
  options: { pollInterval: 10000 },
})(ToursList);

Answer (score 7):

It is the same as this:

```
var func = $filter('number');
func(number[, fractionSize]);
```

The `$filter()` function returns a pointer to another function.

Answer (score 2):

with ES6 or later versions you can do it that way;

```
const divideBoth = (x) => (y) => {
   return x / y;
};
```

one of the reasons that makes this function type useful is when you have a react.js component that needs have callback function instead of doing it inline way(which is **()=>return value**) you can do it the way we did previously. But it is not recommended to use in event callbacks because it gets execute in the first render which might cause issues sometimes