# invoking object methods with extra parenthesis

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I'm looking at the passport.js documentation and I noticed this code:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

    if (err) { return next(err); }

    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {

      if (err) { return next(err); }

      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);

    });

  })(req, res, next);

});
```

What's going on with the (req, res, next) on the second to last line there?

From what I understand, this isn't the right syntax or context for an IIFE, and req, res and next should already be available to the authenticate function.

Thanks,

Zakiir

Comment: i think the answer is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234491/two-sets-of-parentheses-after-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passport.authenticate()` returns a middleware function.

i.e. it has the signature `fn(req, res, next)`.

When you want to run it within a route, you have to invoke it yourself and pass it those arguments so that it can, for example, access data from the request, manipulate the response, etc.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, next);
});
```

That runs your local strategy and does whatever it is that it's configured to do.

Had you just written this:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local')();
});
```

Then `req`, `res`, and `next` are not available to the `authenticate` function.

Simply *invoking* a function does not give it access to variables that are in scope at the call site. For example, this doesn't work:

```
function addOne() {
  x++;
}

app.get('/', function() {
  var x = 99;
  addOne();
})
```

It's when you *define* a function that the function can access variables in scope at the definition site whenever/wherever you invoke it.

Your snippet passes in (defines) a callback that's run after the local strategy has run which lets you run arbitrary logic after the local strategy succeeded or failed to authenticate the user.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return res.redirect('/login'); 
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

This callback can access `req`, `res`, and `next` since they are in scope when the callback function is defined.

However, you still need to pass `req`, `res`, and `next` when invoking passport's `authenticate` function so that it can access them. That function is already defined in the library so, unlike the defined callback function, it did not capture the `res`, `res`, and `next` variables inside the route.

By the time the defined callback function is run, the req/res variables in scope have possibly been mutated by whatever is happening in the local strategy that `authenticate` runs. The callback function gets to read the state of the variables and altogether has the final word — it's essentially post-processing the result of the `authenticate` method, allowing you complete freedom to write your own logic if Passport's built-in options aren't enough.

The difference in scoping behavior between the invocation site vs the definition site of a function is what results in the confusing snippet.