# Javascript Code explaination

Tags: javascript

[image]

I am a javascript beginner, and I do not quite understand this code in the picture, can somebody explain a little ? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid posting text (including code) as an image in the future. Also, to understand exactly what is going on in the example, read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), as I assume that's the part you have problems with.

Comment: That piece of code looks like it comes from some kind of tutorial about functional programming (or higher-order functions, or closures, or something like that). Isn't there any explanation about what it does? Where did you find it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18234552/772035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to explain the code is to fill in the values during each call.

The function `plusGenerator` is a function that takes an `offset` and then returns another function that returns the result of adding `offset` to another number. When you call `plusGenerator(2)`, the function that is returned looks like:

```
var addTwo = function(x) { return x + 2; };
```

You then call `addTwo(15)` which returns `17`.

Comment: That's potentially confusing and misleading for a beginner.