# Understanding basic closure example from wikipedia

Tags: closures

Here is a closure example from the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#First-class_functions)

```
function startAt(x)
   function incrementBy(y)
       return x + y
   return incrementBy

variable closure1 = startAt(1)
variable closure2 = startAt(5)
```

According to the article

> Invoking closure1(3) will return 4, while invoking closure2(3) will return 8.

What is  going on behind the scenes?

1. Why would not this code throw any kind of error in a real programming language?
   incrementBy requires a second variable to do the sum, doesn't it?
2. When we call closure() with an argument, am I right that it being assigned to the y within incrementBy scope?
3. Am I right that closure2 two is binded to a record different from the record that closure1 binded to?

Comment: Does this example help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234491/two-sets-of-parentheses-after-function-call/18234552#18234552 ? The JavaScript closure example is pretty much identical to the closure in your question. Aside from the fact that the inner function is anonymous instead of named `incrementBy`.

Comment: You could also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work . I would say it is a duplicate except that your question seems to be language agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would not this code throw any kind of error in a real programming language? incrementBy requires a second variable to do the sum, doesn't it?

Why would it throw an error? Yes `incrementBy` uses two variables `x` and `y`, but they're both defined. `x` was defined to be `5` when `startAt(5)` was called. `y` was defined to be `3` when `closure2(3)` was called.

> When we call closure() with an argument, am I right that it being assigned to the y within incrementBy scope?

Yes, you are correct that it is being signed to `y` within ***a*** `incrementBy`, but note that there are multiple functions called `incrementBy`. One gets created every time `startAt` is called. In your code there are two separate `incrementBy` functions created by the two calls to `startAt`, each of which has its own context which contains its own `x` in scope.

> Am I right that closure2 two is binded to a record different from the record that closure1 binded to?

Yes, `closure2` and `closure1` are two separate functions, which are both copies of `incrementBy`, but in different contexts.