# Javascript: What is function with two parenthesis brackets ()()?

Tags: javascript

I recall somewhere seeing a function with two parenthesis brackets ()() like:

```
function add_numbers(number1)(number2)
```

What do you call such a function and what’s its usage?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to vote up/accept answer

Answer (score 2):

It is called [function currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying). The first bracket returns another function(lets call it: "myCustomFunc"). The 2nd bracket actually passes the 2nd value (number2) to the myCustomFunc.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234491/two-sets-of-parentheses-after-function-call) answer, the add_numbers function takes one argument (number1) and returns a function, which is then called with argument number2.

Comment: My question? I don't understand

Comment: Basically, function 1 takes one argument, and returns a function, let's call it function 2, which takes another argument and returns a result.