# What is a function with multiple parentheses called?

Tags: javascript

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234552/1417223) elegantly explains how a "function with multiple parentheses" like the one below works:

```
myFunction(3)(4)
```

But I'd like to google it and read more about it. Does this way of constructing a function have a name?

Comment: Looks like a [curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying).

Comment: The link you provide shows an example of IIFE (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossaire/IIFE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "function with multiple parentheses".

However, you can write a function that returns a function. So you pass arguments to your function with 1st parentheses, get a function in return, and pass arguments to the returned function with 2nd parentheses.

This is mainly used for [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossaire/IIFE) when combined with [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp). This technic is also called [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying), as suggested by **@CRice**.