# explain how this javascript function works (found in Douglas Crockford 'How Javascript Works')

Tags: javascript, function, stack, binary-operators

I would like to understand how the `make_binary_op()` function works. It takes two different parameters

1. a function parameter `addop` or `mulop`
2. an array parameter (`my_little_stack`/`my_little_array`)

I've used the firefox debugger to watch the execution but still do not understand how the `make_binary_op()` function works. I get all the pops and pushes, etc.

```js
function make_binary_op(func) {
  return function(my_little_array) {
    let wunth = my_little_array.pop();
    let zeroth = my_little_array.pop();
    my_little_array.push(func(zeroth, wunth));
    return my_little_array;
  };
};

let addop = make_binary_op(function(zeroth, wunth) {
  return zeroth + wunth;
});

let mulop = make_binary_op(function(zeroth, wunth) {
  return zeroth * wunth;
});

let my_little_stack = [];
my_little_stack.push(3);
my_little_stack.push(5);
my_little_stack.push(7);
mulop(my_little_stack); //  my_little_stack is  [3, 35]
addop(my_little_stack); //  my_little_stack is  [38]
let answer = my_little_stack.pop(); //  my_little_stack is  []
console.log(answer);
```

The code works as specified. The value `answer` is `38` and `my_little_stack` is `[]` at the end.

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly is the part you need help with?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález no it doesn't. OP isn't asking for feedback on how to improve it, OP is asking to understand how it works.

Comment: There can't be a single correct answer when you ask for tutoring.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tio.run/##zY/NDoIwEITvfYo9Un/gQIgmxCchhBCsUq0taReJGp4dW8ELiBcvnjbZb3Zm9pRfc1NoXuFaqj3rOsEQLrdMcETBMoN5cYYdJGlMRlu/qk3phXQGRHNgY8GDALigQy0L6@4GciW9O9MKyxU0tcSSgpMBaIa1ltAzWPQwtqiNB5vXxvpM8lTl0bdouP@i@ljXdRv1suKWBMHkALgBSMIVhFH6y4vLv39xmxKXl0vTMD2bB7MGKSmUNEowX6ij19vQuOue) make sense to you?

Comment: I'm am trying to understand how the first function 'make_binary_op(func)' works ... it accepts mulop(zeroth,wunth) as the function parameter and it also is called via the mulop(my_little_stack) ... if I am in the wrong place i will move my question elsewhere

Comment: You're not in the wrong place. And it doesn't accept `mulop` as the function parameter, it accepts `function(zeroth, wunth) { return zeroth * wunth; }` as the function parameter, and the `function(my_little_array) ...` that it returns _is_ `mulop`.

Comment: You just need to understand higher order functions. `make_binary_op` only accepts one argument, and it returns a function. The function it returns is what gets assigned to `addop` and `mulop`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18234491/772035

Comment: This is basically a calculator using "polish reversed notation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to first look at this simpler variant of the algorithm, where there is no such magic as a function that returns a function:

```js
function binary_op(func, my_little_array) { // Two arguments
    let wunth = my_little_array.pop();
    let zeroth = my_little_array.pop();
    my_little_array.push(func(zeroth, wunth));
    return my_little_array;
};

let add = function(zeroth, wunth) { // No call to make_binary_op
  return zeroth + wunth;
};

let mul = function(zeroth, wunth) {
  return zeroth * wunth;
};

let my_little_stack = [];
my_little_stack.push(3);
my_little_stack.push(5);
my_little_stack.push(7);
binary_op(mul, my_little_stack); // we need to pass two arguments
binary_op(add, my_little_stack);
let answer = my_little_stack.pop();
console.log(answer);
```

I think you will be able to understand how this works: the new `binary_op` function takes both a callback function (that performs a operation on two arguments) *and* a stack.
It then pops two values from the stack, passes them to the callback function, gets the result from it, and pushes that result (possibly a sum or a product) on the stack.
The stack has thus reduced in size by 1: two operands were replaced by the `func`'s result on them.

Assuming you follow how this works, now see how we could make it that instead of this:

```
binary_op(mul, my_little_stack);
```

... we could write this:

```
mulop(my_litte_stack);
```

`mulop` would need to be a function that can combine what `mul` does *and* what the above `binary_op` does, in one go.

That is where the function `make_binary_op` comes in: it creates (and returns) a function that is specifically tailored 
to the operator you have in mind (and which you pass as argument). If you pass `mul` to `make_binary_op`, it will produce 
a function that implements the above `binary_op` function, specifically tailored to `mul`: when that created function is invoked 
it will *call* mul. 
But note how that dynamically created function only needs one argument (the stack), because the other argument (`func`) 
is already known to it. It is present in the "closure" in which that function was returned.

### Addendum

One critique on this pattern could be the following observation: while items are added to `my_little_array` using dot-notation (`my_little_array.push`), the operations mul/add have to be expressed like function calls where `my_little_array` is passed as argument. Why could it not be made to work with the dot-notation also, so that you could write `my_little_array.mul()`?

In the current state of the JS language you could do that with a class (constructor) that extends `Array`, so that besides `push` and `pop` it can also support `add` and `mul`:

```js
class PolishCalc extends Array {
    static registerBinaryOp(func) {
        this.prototype[func.name] = function () {
            let wunth = this.pop();
            let zeroth = this.pop();
            this.push(func(zeroth, wunth));
            return this;
        }
    }
}

// Extend the prototype with add and mul methods:
PolishCalc.registerBinaryOp(function add(zeroth, wunth) {
    return zeroth + wunth;
});

PolishCalc.registerBinaryOp(function mul(zeroth, wunth) {
    return zeroth * wunth;
});

let polishCalc = new PolishCalc;
polishCalc.push(3, 5, 7);
let answer = polishCalc.mul().add().pop(); // the method calls can be chained...
console.log(answer);
```