# Problem with function calls that returns function and assigned to variable as expression

Tags: javascript, function

I've seen a code like this:

```
function operationType(type){
    return function(a,b){
        console.log(`It's a ${type}`);
        return a+b;
    }
}
const sum=operationType(type);
```

has only one parameter called `type`? It looks like when i call the `sum` function it's only consider the `returned  function`

And what i don't understand is they way arguments are passed when the function is called like this `sum(4,4)` and returns :

```
It's and addition
8
```

How can we call the function `sum(4,4)` when the `operationType(type)` function is function that's is really defined.

What I really want to say is here : `const sum=operationType('addition')` we do not pass the anonymous function that calculate the sum,how does it guesses??

How can `sum(4,4) = operationType('addition')`.I'm really lost

Comment: This question is likely to be closed, so please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function, then see if you can whittle the question to something less broad that can be answered specifically.

Comment: `operationType` returns *a function*. So `const sum=operationType(type);` is essentially equal to `const sum = function(a,b){ console.log(\`It's a ${type}\`); return a+b; }` (the inner function that is returned from `operationType`

Comment: Also relevant question: [Two sets of parentheses after function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234491/two-sets-of-parentheses-after-function-call)