# why it is returning different outcome ? (es6 arrow function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to push some data onto the firebase.

Here is my handleSubmit function in App.js

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const note = {
      title: this.state.title,
      body: this.state.body
    };
    this.props.saveNotes(note);
    this.setState({
      title: "",
      body: ""
    });
  };
```

and this is my saveNote function, and it works fine.

```
function saveNotes(note) {
  database.push(note);
}
```

I wonder Why pushing onto database is not working with using arrow function like this

```
function saveNotes(note) {
  return () => database.push(note);
}
```

Comment: One is doing a push, the other *returns a function* that will do the push when called. So, the first one you have to call as `saveNotes(note)` the second option you have to call it as `saveNotes(note)()`

Comment: A question explaining the concept but from the opposite side [Two sets of parentheses after function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18234491) also more about the same thing [What do multiple arrow functions mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32782922)

Comment: Because you are returning function from a function and the inner function is never being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want following to work:

```
function saveNotes(note) {
  return () => database.push(note);
}
```

then you should call `saveNotes(note)` like this.

```
this.props.saveNotes(note)();
```

OR

```
const arrowFunction = this.props.saveNotes(note);
arrowFunction();
```

Because you are returning a reference to a function not a result of a function

Please refer to guide [IIEF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

But this does not sound suitable here as you can simply call like this:

```
const saveNotes = (note) => database.push(note);
```

Comment: That's unrelated to IIFE, it's called currying.

Answer (score 1):

**Because you used function inside function**

if you want rewrite function using **arrow function** syntax you should do the following:

```
const saveNotes = (note) => {
  database.push(note);
}
```

or

```
const saveNotes = (note) => database.push(note);
```

---

if you want to learn more about arrow function check out [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

the last saveNote function return a function `() => { return database.push(note) }` so it doesnt operate push action.