# Why not using "require('express')()"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

To create a simple Web server with NodeJS and Express, all the tutorials giving examples like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Started"))

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send("Yaaa")
})
```

My question is, Why not write it like this?

```
const app = require('express')();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Started"))

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send("Yaaa")
})
```

The only difference is merging lines 1 and 2, as far as I'm not going to use/need the "express" constant anymore.

Is that wrong? And why?

Comment: In the first way you also have access to the variable `express` which may expose more API stuff you might want?

Comment: Perhaps they use the first approach because it's easier to comprehend. People have trouble grasping [functions that return other functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18234491).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't need access to the express module elsewhere in this file, then doing:

```
const app = require('express')();
```

is the best way.

But if we require to use to this express module again and again. Such as below

```
const app = require('express')();

const friendsRouter = require('express').Router();
```

**Then it becomes a problem and you have require it again and again.**

So to make our code less redundant, we use normal given approach. As in below code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const friendRouter = express.Router();
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know about express framework. Express exposes us to a lot of useful functions. If we don't `require` or `import` express in our application then, Our application will not be able to use those functions.

For example if you are creating some REST APIs then, We need our APIs to take `form-data` or `raw` as input. If we want to allow our application to take `raw-json` as input then, we need to add a middleware which consumes a built-in express function.

```
app.use(express.json())
```

If you want create an application that has a seperate folder for all the routes. Then, we use `express.Routes()` for that. That's how we create routes file in seperate routes folder:

```
import express from 'express';
import userController from 'path/to/user/controller';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/follow/:userid/:following', helper.verifyToken, userController.follow);

router.get('/someRoute', userController.someAction);

export default router;
```

Similarly, If we want to serve some static `HTML` or some `react-build`. Then, we use `express.static()` inside `app.use()` middleware like this:

```
app.use(express.static('/path/to/static/folder'));
```