# How does combining higher-order functions work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, callback, higher-order-functions, currying

The first book I have bought on JavaScript was unfortunately not for beginners.
The book is "the joy of JavaScript" from Luis Atencio. I am still trying to understand some concept in this book 2 years after...

There is a code I still don't understand today. Can you lehp me to understand how is this possible?

```js
const identity = a => a;
const fortyTwo = () => 42;

const notNull = a => a !== null;
const square  = a => a ** 2;

const safeOperation = (operation, guard, recover) =>
  input => guard(input, operation) || recover();

const onlyIf = validator => (input, operation) =>
  validator(input) ? operation(input) : NaN;

const orElse = identity;

const safeSquare = safeOperation(
  square,
  onlyIf(notNull),
  orElse(fortyTwo)
);

console.log( safeSquare(2) ); // 4
console.log( safeSquare(null) ); // 42
```

How is this possible to do `safeSquare(2)` when `safeSquare` is a function with 3 arguments (`square`, `onlyIf(null)`, `orElse(fortyTwo)`). I think the 2 here is the input in `safeOperation`, but how the 2 is passed in the `safeOperation` function. I just don't figure this out.

I know the basic of currying, but here I don't get it.

Comment: Consider: What does `safeOperation` return? Look at the structure of that function, and the inner `input => ...` part.

Comment: `safeSquare` is *not* a "function with 3 arguments". It's whatever function *the call to `safeOperation(...)` returned!* `foo => bar` is a function definition, `foo(bar)` is a function *call*.

Comment: what is `identity`?

Comment: *"safesquare is a function with 3 arguments"* - No it isn't.  `safeSquare` is whatever the returned result from calling `safeOperation` with three arguments ends up being.  `safeOperation` appears to return a function which accepts one argument.

Comment: I think the real confusion here stems from the lack of braces and the `x => y => z` format used. If these were expressed long-form as `function(x) { return function(y) { return z } }` the structure becomes more clear.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257078/discussion-on-question-by-djbone-how-does-combining-higher-order-functions-work); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

### A bit of theory

First, let's talk about a bit of theory. Namely, what is [beta reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B2-reduction_2). Wikipedia has a lot of theory but the simple explanation is that you can replace a function with its application. For example if you have

```
const fn = x => x + 1;

const result = fn(2);
```

the last part can be replaced with the function body:

```
const fn = x => x + 1;
//              ^^^^^^ -----+ for f(2)
//                          | then x = 2
const result = 2 + 1; // <--+ therefore we can substitute here
```

The two pieces of code are equivalent. The name of beta reduction is less important than the principle here. The call of the function is replaceable with the body but with the parameter replaced.

This holds true even when [the function returns another function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18234491):

```
const add = a => b => a + b;
```

This is a function that takes one parameter, returns a second function which takes another parameter. When the second function is called, then the final result is the first parameter `a` added to the second parameter `b`.

For clarity, that is the same as this longer way of writing the same:

```
function add(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

However, if we apply beta reduction the same rules apply as before, calling `add(2)` can be replaced with the body where `a = 2`:

```js
const add = a => b => a + b;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^ -----+ for add(2)
//                                | a = 2
const result1 = b => 2 + b; // <--+ therefore we can substitute
const result2 = add(2); // same as the above

console.log( result1(3) ); // 2 + 3 = 5
console.log( result2(3) ); // 2 + 3 = 5
```

Now we can look at how this can be used.

### Now some practice

The principle of beta reduction can now inform how this code works:

> How is this possible to do `safeSquare(2)` when `safeSquare` is a function with 3 arguments (`square`, `onlyIf(null)`, `orElse(fortyTwo)`)

The `safeOperation` function is the one that takes three parameters. Therefore, its call can be substituted with the body

```
const safeOperation = (operation, guard, recover) =>
  input => guard(input, operation) || recover();
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the body that we can substitute
```

Making

```
const safeSquare = safeOperation(
  square,          // ------------------------------------------------+
  onlyIf(notNull), // ---------------------------------------------+  |
  orElse(fortyTwo) // ------------------------------------------+  |  |
); //                                                           |  |  |
// equivalent to:                                               |  |  |
input => onlyIf(notNull)(input, square) || orElse(fortyTwo)()// |  |  |
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     |  |  |
//              ^                 ^                ^            |  |  |
//              |                 |                |            |  |  |
//              |                 |                +------------+  |  |
//              |                 +--------------------------------+  |
//              +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

We can continue beta reducing the other functions. However, that is left for an exercise to the reader. The main point here is that when `safeOperation` is called with three parameters it returns a function with only one parameter. That one parameter function is assigned to `safeSquare`, which is why `safeSquare(2)` is then a legal call.

### Back to theory and nomenclature

#### First-class functions

The thing that enables this behaviour is called [first-class functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function) (see also [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)). Simply put "first-class" means this is an type of value the programming language can handle directly - it can be assigned to variables, it can be passed into function calls, etc. Other first class types are strings or numbers, for example. We can do the same things with them:

```
const str = "hello";
const num = 4;

someFunction( "a string" );
otherFunction( 42 );
```

When first-class functions are possible, we also get the following:

#### Higher order functions

These are functions that do at least one of: take a function as parameter or return a function as a result. These are the basis of writing reusable code where one part of the operation can change. Good examples where higher order functions are used are [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (among other array methods). These two go over an array and do *something* with each member: `.filter()` will include or exclude it, while `.map()` will change it. The logic for going over the array is the same for all calls to `.filter()` or `.map()` but the way the item is checked is determined by the callback:

```js
const fruits = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];

const onlyOdd = fruits.filter( x => x % 2 === 1 );
console.log(onlyOdd); // [ 1, 3, 5 ]

const allPlus20 = fruits.map( x => x + 20 );
console.log(allPlus20); // [ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Functional programming relies on higher order functions to build up applications and handle data with.

### Currying

This is a special kind of a higher order function, not just any. Specifically a function that takes multiple parameters is converted to an equivalent series of functions that require one parameter each:

```
const regularAdd = (a, b) => a + b;
const curriedAdd = a => b => a + b;

const regularPythagoreanCheck = (a, b, c) =>   a**2 + b**2 === c**2;
const curriedPythagoreanCheck = a => b => c => a**2 + b**2 === c**2;


//distance between two 2D points
const regularDistance = (x1, y1, x2, y2) =>     Math.sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 );
const curriedDistance = x1 => y1 => x2 => y2 => Math.sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 );
```

And so on. This type of conversion is useful when working mainly in functions. But I will not go too deep in it - it is just worth keeping in mind that not any higher order function is curried. Just if it is a series of one parameter functions.

Modern curry implementations are less rigorous than this, though. A modern way to curry will accept one or more parameters at each step until all expected parameters are satisfied. For example using [`curry` from Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry) which converts a function to a curried variant:

```js
const regularDistance = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => Math.sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 );
const curriedDistance = R.curry(regularDistance);

console.log(regularDistance(1, 1, 4, 5)); // original

console.log(curriedDistance(1)(1)(4)(5)); // four 1 parameter functions
console.log(curriedDistance(1, 1)(4, 5)); // two 2 parameter functions
console.log(curriedDistance(1)(1)(4, 5)); // two 1 parameter functions + one 2 parameter
console.log(curriedDistance(1, 1, 4, 5)); // 4 parameter function
//etc
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and thanks Vlaz to the explanation... That's very nice and valuable !! That's so crazy to have a so well done and explained answer, to take so much time to respond to me...

Answer (score 2):

**abstraction distraction**

VLAZ has done a great job explaining the mechanics of the code and the background theory. I wanted to remark on the ergonomics of the original code and why it's not a great example for beginners -

- `identity` - what is this function? Aside from being renamed to `orElse`, it's unused.
- `fortyTwo` - some constant value, ok, but why is it inside a thunk?
- `safeOperation` - unfamiliar pattern is just `if..else` in disguise
- `onlyIf` - sometimes returns `NaN`, why?
- `orElse` - a copy of `identity`?

I would like to demonstrate the same program but with different lines drawn in the sand -

```js
const always = x =>
  () => x

const eq = x => y =>
  x == y

const square = x =>
  x * x

const when = (predicate, ifTrue, ifFalse) =>
  x => predicate(x) ? ifTrue(x) : ifFalse(x)

const safeSquare = when(
  eq(null),
  always(42),
  square,
)

console.log(safeSquare(2))     // 4
console.log(safeSquare(null))  // 42
```

It may not be a perfect demonstration that leaves no question in the learner's mind, but hopefully the knowledge you acquired from VLAZ can help you see these abstractions as more intuitive and generally useful -

- `always` makes a function which returns a constant value
- `eq` is `==` as a function, in curried form
- `when` is the familiar `if..else` as a function

```js
const safeSquare = when(    // if                   if 
  eq(null),                 //   (condition)          equal to null?
  always(42),               //   { true... }          always 42
  square,                   //   else { false... }    (or) square 
)
```

---

**identity crisis**

For those wondering about `identity`, it is the **identity element** in the function monoid, where `compose` is the **binary operation** -

> What is a monoid?
>
> A set *S* equipped with a binary operation *S × S → S*, is a **monoid** if it satisfies the following two axioms:
>
> **associativity**
> For all *a*, *b* and *c* in *S*, the equation *(a × b) × c = a × (b × c)* holds.
>
> **identity element**
> There exists an element *e* in *S* such that for every element *a* in *S*, the equalities *e × a = a* and *a × e = a* hold.

The function monoid -

```js
// identity element
const identity = a =>
  a

// binary operation
const compose = (f, g) =>
  x => f(g(x))
```

Upholds the monoid laws -

```
// associativity
compose(compose(f, g), h) == compose(f, compose(g, h))

// identity
compose(f, identity) == compose(identity, f)
```

Maybe the text already covered all of this before presenting you with the code in your post. If not, we can see why including `identity` introduces more questions than it answers.

Comment: The code came from a chapter in a book introducing what functional programming is. I agree that `safeOperation` is really just an "if". I also fully agree with your real usage with using `always` to create thunks. I'm just trying to say that the book attempts to introduce few concepts, hence for example the `fortyTwo = () => 42` - it's showing using functions as data with that. It discusses this briefly, then later moves onto the code seen. I didn't read further to see if it streamlined the code but at the point it shows the code, it's supposed to make sense to a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for the context, VLAZ. I'm not familiar with the book but my sadness for OP's 2-year struggle motivated me to write this post :D

Comment: I've read that book multiple time and my dream is to understand it fully :) i know it almost by heart, but yeah i'm struggled reading it and i think i'm not the only one, it tries to explain really advanced techniques I see this book as a challenge, not as a really well explained book. So my challenge to understand it is why i'm here and i don't regret at all because now i have understood the code and i thank you again for that... There's chance i'll come back again in come time because this challenge is noit an easy one for me !