# Store filtered values from angularjs variable in new variable

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a variable defined in a controller that stores json values:

```
$rootScope.fullList;
```

I have been able to successfully filter the results using a filter I found to return only exact matches to a keyword and display the results on my page.  I need to store these filtered values into a new variable.

```
$scope.filteredList = $rootScope.fullList| exactMatch:'STATUS';
```

Something like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a filter in a controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)

Comment: What is the structure of `$rootScope.fullList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `_filter`: [LINK](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)

like:

```
   $scope.filteredList = _.filter($scope.fullList, function(item) {
      return !(nodeClient.name == 'STATUS');
     });
```

*as a side note*

How `_filter` works:

filter`_.filter(list, iterator, [context])`
        Alias: **select**
        
        Looks through each value in the **list**, returning an array of all
        the values that pass a truth test (**iterator**). Delegates to the
        native **filter** method, if it exists.

```
var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Actually `_filter` has list of options that might help you in the future as well

Comment: This was interesting reading, but I achieved the result I was looking for by storing the value for my filter as a variable in $scope and changing the value based on user interaction.