# AngularJS - convert dates in controller

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, datetime-format, ng-controller

Could anyone please suggest me how to convert date from this `1387843200000` format into this `24/12/2013` **inside my controller**?

Just FYI my dates are stored in this way & when binding to edit form with `input type="date"` field is not being populated at all.

**[#Plunker demo here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/akLekgX7b1rcaMg6B9rI?p=preview)**

EditCtrl

```
app.controller("EditCtrl", [ "$scope", "$filter", "db" function ($scope, $filter, db){

    // this gets me an item object
    var item = db.readItem();

    // item date = 1387843200000
    // this returns undefined 
    item.date = $filter('date')(date[ item.date, "dd/MM/yyyy"]);

}]);
```

Edit.html - template

```
<form name="editForm" class="form-validate">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Event date.</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="event.date" id="date" required />
        </div>

        <a href="#/" class="btn btn-danger ">Cancel</a>
        <button id="addEvent" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="isClean() || editForm.$invalid" ng-click="saveEvent()">Save event.</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert in the controller? You can use the date filter to format the date in your view if you just need a display-able value.

Comment: @JustinNiessner - my dates are stored in this way & when binding to edit form with `input type="date"` field is not being populated

Comment: You can use moment.js angularjs date time filter - https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
item.date = $filter('date')(item.date, "dd/MM/yyyy"); // for conversion to string
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

But if you are using HTML5 type="date" then the ISO format yyyy-MM-dd MUST be used.

```
item.dateAsString = $filter('date')(item.date, "yyyy-MM-dd");  // for type="date" binding


<input type="date" ng-model="item.dateAsString" value="{{ item.dateAsString }}" pattern="dd/MM/YYYY"/>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

NOTE: use of pattern="" with type="date" looks non-standard, but it appears to work in the expected way in Chrome 31.

Comment: Hi,I tried to implement as suggested,but it is not working for me.

Comment: Hi,I tried to implement as suggested,but it is not working for me. my response from spring webservice is {"basicPersonalInfo":{"empNo":"04005001","dob":490645800000},"communicationInfo":null}  , I need to display it in my  bootstrap/HTML5 date input field. I used the filter in my controller like  $scope.basicInfo = BasicInformationService.query();     $scope.basicInfo.$promise.then(function(data){      $scope.basicInfo.basicPersonalInfo.dob = $filter('date')(data.basicPersonalInfo.dob, "yyyy-MM-dd");     
 });  any help is appreciated

Comment: ok I changed the formatting in my controller like this and it seem to work, not sure if it is the right way.  $scope.basicInfo.basicPersonalInfo.dob =new Date($filter('date')(data.basicPersonalInfo.dob, "yyyy-MM-dd"));

Comment: My date is coming like this from API DateTime : "2017/12/15" but doing this {{M.DateTime | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}} not changing date format.How do i format it inside the expression?

Answer (score 17):

create a filter.js and you can make this as reusable

```
angular.module('yourmodule').filter('date', function($filter)
{
    return function(input)
    {
        if(input == null){ return ""; }
        var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        return _date.toUpperCase();
    };
});
```

view

```
<span>{{ d.time | date }}</span>
```

or in controller

```
var filterdatetime = $filter('date')( yourdate );
```

[Date filtering and formatting in Angular js.](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html)

Comment: It seems there's already a date filter built into AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 2):

All solutions here doesn't really bind the model to the input because you will have to change back the `dateAsString` to be saved as `date` in your object (in the controller after the form will be submitted).

If you don't need the binding effect, but just to show it in the input,

a simple could be:

```
<input type="date" value="{{ item.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}" id="item_date" />
```

Then, if you like, in the controller, you can save the edited date in this way:

> ```
>   $scope.item.date = new Date(document.getElementById('item_date').value).getTime();
> ```

**be aware:** in your controller, you have to declare your `item` variable as `$scope.item` in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest in Javascript:

```
var item=1387843200000;
var date1=new Date(item);
```

and then date1 is a Date.

Comment: Yes your right where we want to convert our time stamp to date