# How to format Jquery-ui date

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, date

I found a jquery-ui angular date picker directive to use. It works fine except the format when it is populated with a date from the db. right now it shows 2014-08-10T00:00:00. I need the mm-dd-yy format. also when I open the datepicker the default value is todays date, I need it to show up on the date from the db.
I cannot use angular-ui datepicker because of the design and look. thanks
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1z89tfPC4A4RPGzQdx4u?p=preview)

```
app.directive("datepicker1", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var updateModel = function (dateText) {
                // call $apply to bring stuff to angular model
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                });
            };

            var options = {
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                // handle jquery date change
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    updateModel(dateText);
                }
            };

            // jqueryfy the element
            elem.datepicker(options);
        }
    }
});

 <input type="text" style="width:150px" ng-model="currentItem.ChangeOrderDate" datepicker1 />
```

Comment: You can format the date in the controller at `$scope.date = '2014-08-10T00:00:00';`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131553/angularjs-convert-dates-in-controller

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

Comment: Can't use ui-date for visual reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *need* to use jQuery (and not angular-ui, which I too recommend), you have to take several steps:

1. Implement the `ngModelCtrl.$render` function. It needs to transform the model to a user presentable value. This is easy using `$.datepicker.formatDate()` ([ref](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)):

   ```
   ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
       var d = new Date(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue), txt;
       if( isNaN(d.getTime()) ) {
           txt = "";
       }
       else {
           txt = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", d);
       }
       elem.val(txt);
   };
   ```

   Details on this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) - check "custom controls"
2. The presentation, i.e. the `<h1>Selected date: {{date}}</h1>` part, has to use a display filter for the date. Luckily Angular provides us with the `date` filter:

   ```
   <h1>Selected date: {{date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</h1>
   ```
3. I would also suggest storing a date object in the controller, so:

   ```
   $scope.date = new Date('2014-08-10T00:00:00');
   ```

   and:

   ```
   var updateModel = function (dateText) {
       // call $apply to bring stuff to angular model
       scope.$apply(function () {
           ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($.datepicker.parseDate(FORMAT, dateText));
       });
   };
   ```

A working plunker implementing this: http://plnkr.co/edit/J1acskcSh4xXI3kan32W