# AngularJS form is not binding to $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

```html
 <form novalidate class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <div class="text-capitalize">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsluga3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usluga</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select id="inputUsluga3" class="form-control">
                                <option>Kombi</option>
                                <option>Hotel</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputOdDatum3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Od datuma</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="inputOdDatum3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="fromDate" data-max-date="{{untilDate}}" placeholder="Početak perioda" bs-datepicker data-date-format="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputDoDatum3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Do datuma</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="inputDoDatum3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="untilDate" data-min-date="{{fromDate}}" placeholder="Kraj perioda" bs-datepicker data-date-format="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputStanica" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stanica</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select id="inputStanica" ng-model="airport" class="form-control">
                                <option>PUY</option>
                                <option>ZAG</option>
                                <option>SPL</option>
                                <option>DUB</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getData()">Dohvati podatke</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

MY Http request looks like this

```
        $scope.getData = function() {
            $http.get("/Services/JoppdService.svc/getKombiImport/" + $scope.fromDate + "/" + $scope.untilDate + "/" + $scope.airport)
                 .success(function (response) {
                     $scope.education = response;
                 });
        }
```

After submiting i have request in console that looks like this

http://localhost:8080/Services/JoppdService.svc/getKombiImport/undefined/undefined/undefined

dateFrom, dateUntil and airport is not binded. Where is problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-submit`, bind the required parameters into an object `obj`, like `obj.fromDate`, `obj.untilDate`, and `obj.airport` in the form. Use button type as `submit`

Your html would transform into,

```
<form novalidate class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="getData(obj)">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <div class="text-capitalize">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUsluga3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usluga</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select id="inputUsluga3" class="form-control">
                                <option>Kombi</option>
                                <option>Hotel</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputOdDatum3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Od datuma</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="inputOdDatum3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.fromDate" data-max-date="{{obj.formDate}}" placeholder="Početak perioda" bs-datepicker data-date-format="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputDoDatum3" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Do datuma</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input id="inputDoDatum3" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.untilDate" data-min-date="{{obj.untilDate}}" placeholder="Kraj perioda" bs-datepicker data-date-format="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputStanica" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stanica</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select id="inputStanica" ng-model="obj.airport" class="form-control">
                                <option>PUY</option>
                                <option>ZAG</option>
                                <option>SPL</option>
                                <option>DUB</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Dohvati podatke</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Pass `obj` in `ng-submit` method `getData()` which now looks like, `getData(obj)`

You got to convert the fromDate and untilDate into String. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131553/angularjs-convert-dates-in-controller). Replace `convertToString()` below with the solution mentioned in that link.

Then in your controller `getData()` would look like,

```
$scope.getData = function(obj) {
    var fromDate = convertToString(obj.fromDate);
    var untilDate = convertToString(obj.untilDate);
    var airport = obj.airport;
            $http.get("/Services/JoppdService.svc/getKombiImport/"+fromDate+"/"+untilDate+"/"+.airport)
                 .success(function (response) {
                     $scope.education = response;
                 });
        }
```

Also, do not have empty spaces (" ") while forming URLs.

If you want to initialize anything, use `ng-init` like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap your content inside   if you have not already
Also you should use  for  date inputs

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ng-init` to initialize these values like `ng-init="fromDate = 0"`.

You could also just declare these variables at the begining of your controller such as `$scope.fromDate = 0;`