# AngularJS : format date input

Tags: angularjs, cordova, date

i have an input type Date in my HTML.(i'm working with angularjs )
i used it like this :

```
< input ng-model="voyage.dateRetour" type="date">   
{{voyage.dateRetour}}
```

i created a pdf with jsPDF and i use the inputs form the complete the pdf so i did :

```
     $scope.createPDFs= function (filename) { 
     var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text(13, 95, 'Retour : '+$scope.voyage.dateRetour );
```

and it gives me : Fri Aug 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))

i dont know how to change the format to short format like DD-MM-YYYY .

i tried to do a filter like :

```
$filter('date')($scope.voyage.dateRetour, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: try replacing {{voyage.dateRetour}} with {{voyage.dateRetour | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}

Comment: thank you for responding, i need the date in my controller for use it in pdf with jsPDF , so i need a filter in my controller not in HTML.

Comment: Similar question is already answered in previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131553/angularjs-convert-dates-in-controller

Comment: create a plunkr where we can see the exact issue you're facing please.

Comment: i can't create plunker because i need the plugin of jsPDF but i can explain :
i created a pdf with jsPDF and i use the inputs form the complete the pdf so i did    
$scope.createPDFs= function (filename) {      
         var doc = new jsPDF();
     doc.text(13, 95, 'Retour :   ' + $scope.voyage.dateRetour );        
and it gives me Fri Aug 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{date | date:'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm a'}}
    <br />{{date}}</div>
```

i.e using the filter in the html itself.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/srnug/

Comment: sorry i think i didn't ask wwell my question , for the html i just tested it , i need the date in my controller for use it in pdf with jsPDF , so i need a filter in my controller not in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this it will help you:--

```js
function MyController($scope){
  $scope.MyObje = {mydate:new Date()}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="date" ng-model="MyObje.mydate">

  {{MyObje.mydate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First split for date and time. Second to replace all "-" to "/"

```
< input ng-model="voyage.dateRetour" type="date">   
{{voyage.dateRetour.split("T")[0].split("-").join("/");}}
```

Comment: Thanks you but it doesn't work for me like i said in a comment i need the date in my controller for use it in pdf with jsPDF , so i need a filter in my controller not in HTML.

Comment: okay, write the code in the bracket in your controller. it will work if date is given

Answer (score 0):

```
/* code to format date into controller */

 app.controller('homeController', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.date = $filter("date")(new Date('2017-12-04'),'dd/MM/yyyy');
    alert($scope.date);
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @VishalChhodwani this is just a sample u can modify as per your requirement. U can call it inside a function or use in html. In short you can modify this code as your need