# Use date filter in ng options concatinated field

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I am using  JSON data to populate a dropdown list. Here i have multiple fields for start and end time. I am concatinating them at ng options and using a date filter to rearrange date time. But the filter seems not working with the second value inside ng option.

```
ng-options="(session.SessionStartTime|date:'MMM/dd hh:mm' +'- '+session.max|date:'MMM/dd hh:mm')
```

it is working fine if i doesnot concatinate two values

Can anyone help

Comment: I don't know how you made it working without concatenation..as you have wrong `ng-options` syntax..It should be `ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items"`

Comment: But it works fine if you concatinate it at ng options field

Comment: Any way i have solved the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[look into this fiddle for your problem solution](http://jsfiddle.net/td2nz/)

```
<select
        ng-model="datedemo"
        ng-options="(a.max|date:'MMM/dd hh:mm') +' - '+  (a.SessionStartTime|date:'MMM/dd hh:mm') for a in session"></select>
```

i have found this link where explanation is done.
[here is explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131553/angularjs-convert-dates-in-controller)