# How to set the format for input type date to be dd-MM-yyyy Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to setup a value in Angular controller for the input which is of type date but the problem is it always shows the value in yyyy-MM-dd format.

How can I change it to display in **dd-MM-yyyy** format?

Markup:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="startDate">
```

and the controller

```
  $scope.startDate = $filter('date')('2014-02-27T10:00:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - convert dates in controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131553/angularjs-convert-dates-in-controller)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is work for you.
Here you can see how to do that `jsfiddle`