# Convert to TimeStamp in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an api returning timestamp variable. When I print in AngularJs it shows as 1488195848000.But I want that to be displayed as 2017-02-28 14:49:48(In Timestamp format)

How do I convert in controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - convert dates in controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131553/angularjs-convert-dates-in-controller)

Comment: Go through https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date#examples at least once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert that variable in HTML,

```
{{variable | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
```

And in case of JS,

```
$filter('date')(variable, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Note: In case of JS, do not forget to add $filter as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can format date in AngularJS using the pipe operator and the date filter

```
<span>{{1488195848000| date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

In the controller you need to make use of filter function to format the date
like

```
var _date = $filter('date')(_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: How do I do that in controller ?