# Getting a filtered ng-repeat to the controller

Tags: angularjs

Let's say you have this ng-repeat with some filters

```
ng-repeat="city in cities" | filter={region:region} | filter=searchQuery etc..
```

I'd to run some logic on all cities that is filtred. For example summarize the population in all filtred cities. Is there any easy way to do this? Just get a list to the controller on all items that is filtred in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually inject the $filter service in a controller and use it there.

Related thread, so not going to copy paste his answer:
[How to use a filter in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)