# AngularJS ng-repeat filter on unformatted date expression

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have some JSON I pull into my Angular application.  I use ng-repeat to output the JSON to the page, but I would now like to filter on a date field.  I can filter on the necessary field using the ng-model query.  However the data that comes from the server is converted to the specific date format in a filter in the repeater itself.  Therefore using the filter box does not work as expected.  I am uncertain at this point how I would convert what's entered into the ng-model text box into the required format.

```
Enter the time you left: <input ng-model="query.start">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="incident in Traffic | filter: query">
      <h3>{{incident.description}}</h3>
      <p>Start: {{incident.start | jsonDate : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</p>
      <p>End: {{incident.end| jsonDate : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, and what exactly do you want to accomplish here? Examples of date data would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use Angular UI's [datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) to provide a nice date picker user interface instead of having the user type a date manually. With that in place, your `ng-model` is a true JavaScript Date object instead of a string. When it changes, you can compare it against dates in your server data and [filter them at the controller level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller). Push only those that match into a separate array, and display *that* array with your `ng-repeat`, instead of the original server-provided array.