# Filter the Data from json or Server in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have json data with following information

```
[
{
"city":"Bangalore",
"dob":"04-Oct-2014",
"age":24,
"maritalStatus":"Single"
},
{
"city":"Bangalore",
"dob":"04-Oct-2014",
"age":24,
"maritalStatus":"Single"
},
{
"city":"Chennai",
"dob":"04-Oct-2014",
"age":24,
"maritalStatus":"Single"
}
]
```

This data shown in list format

```
<ul class="userInfo">
<div   ng-repeat="user in users " >
  <li class="btn-default">
    <div class="userDetails">
      <div class="userPosition">{{user.city}}</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

During HTTP request

```
userDirectory.controller("userListControl", function($scope,$rootScope, $http)
        {

            $http.get('data/userData.json').success (function(data){
               $scope.users = data;
        var usersDb = TAFFY();
        usersDb.insert(data);
            });
    });
```

Here, The data is coming from userData.json file.

My Question is,

Before the loading page. I will declare city = "bangalore".

So based on city. I have to show the data based on city. I want to avoid other datas except city:bangalore from json.

How can i filter particular city datas. I dont want use filter function. I have to filter at this stage

$scope.users = data;
Because i am using JS Db here. Then only i can store these data here and process in future

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to use a filter in a controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about your exact scenario but you can very well do

```
 $http.get('data/userData.json').success (function(data){
    var city='bangalore';   //can be set anywhere 
    $scope.users = data.filter(function(item){return item.city===city;});
    var usersDb = TAFFY();
    usersDb.insert($scope.users);
 });
```

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works on all modern browsers (ie 9 and above)

Else implement an Angular filter and use it the controller using `$filter` service:

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can injecto $filter into your controller like this:

```
userDirectory.controller("userListControl", function($scope,$rootScope, $http, $filter)
    {

        $http.get('data/userData.json').success (function(data){
           var cityFilter = {city: 'Bangalore'};

           $scope.users = $filter('filter')(data, cityFilter); //Then here is your result.
           var usersDb = TAFFY();
           usersDb.insert(data);
        });
});
```

[Here is $filter document in angularjs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)