# Find an Object by id via angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently handing down JSON data from Rail in the DOM. It looks like this:

```
> gon.posts
[
  { id: 1, name: "Post 1", related_post_ids: [3] },
  { id: 2, name: "Post 2", related_post_ids: [2, 3] },
  { id: 3, name: "Post 3", related_post_ids: [1, 2] }
]
```

How would I be able to write some AngularJS (I'm ruby) so that I could execute this pseudocode:

```
// Using "Post 1" and mapping to its related posts.
> gon.posts[0].related_posts
[
  { id: 3, name: "Post 3", related_post_ids: [1, 2] }
]

// Then being able to do this recursively to make development with the JSON easier:
> gon.posts[0].related_posts[0].related_posts
[
  { id: 1, name: "Post 1", related_post_ids: [3] },
  { id: 2, name: "Post 2", related_post_ids: [2, 3] }
]
```

It would also be helpful if you could show how to do this via a `map` or `each` function with AngularJS.

---

A user commented that [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would be useful, but I'm not looking for a gross solution, I'm looking for the best, minimal, DRYest solution via AngularJS.

---

[Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) has a `find()` method. If I was able to use Ember and load the data up, I would be able to easily search, but I would still need something like an `ActiveRecord::Proxy` object in JS to be able to handle the delegations and I'm not sure how to meta program new object types in JS.

Comment: Can you post your code so far? Also, look into `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: Is there a way to meta program JS functions to be able to handle `Array.prototype.filter` without having to re-wrap the method?

Comment: Actually, wait, shouldn't there be an AngularJS helper for this?

Comment: You don't have to "re-wrap" the method, if you already have a named method, you can just pass in the method name (think of it as a function pointer) to filter, no need to wrap it in a new function.

Comment: What do you mean by a "named method"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular's build in $filter service for that. 
Check out this question

[How to use a filter in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)

Comment: I don't think a filter should go inside of a controller. I have a feeling that might lead to some serious confusion from other developers, especially since its business logic. Is there a better way to use a `$filter` to filter business logic?

Comment: Is there a well maintained JS bower package for `$filter`s that would suffice for data modelling?

Comment: Haki, can you provide an example using Lodash and where you place the code inside of an Angular application?

Comment: Lodash is a very common general purpose library for data and object manipulation in javascript (you might know underscore). It has nothing to do with angular. You can inject it as a value. e.g `app.value('lodash',_)` and then into your controller via regular injection and use the functions as you wish.