# Can't access the variable from newly created filter variable of ng-repeat in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat like this :

```
<a class="item item-avatar" ng-click="loadProfile({{student.pi_id}})" 
ng-repeat="student in filteredStudents = (students | filter:model.txtSearch)" >
            <img src="./img/man.png">
            <h2>{{student.pi_name}}</h2>
            <p>{{student.pi_hp}}</p>

        </a>
```

the question is how can I access the filteredStudents variable? as I can't access it by using $scope.filteredStudents; in the controller

Comment: Please show how you intend to use `filteredStudents` in the controller.

Comment: If you want to use filteredStudents in controller, then do the filtering in the controller.

Comment: I just want to access it so for instance I want to return the length of the filteredStudents thus, I wrote

 console.log($scope.filteredStudents.length);

but, it returns null.

@ArghyaC : any link or example of that?

Answer (score 0):

When you are applying the filter in view the filtered value is not accessible in controller.

If you need the filtered data in your controller you need to do filtering in your controller like:

`$scope.filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredStudents, $scope.model.txtSearch)`

Answer (score 0):

Inject filter in your controller

```
function YourController($scope, $filter)
{
}
```

then, use the filter in controller itself

```
$scope.filteredStudents = $filter('yourFilterName')(model.txtSearch);
```

then in html,

```
<a class="item item-avatar" ng-click="loadProfile({{student.pi_id}})" ng-repeat="student in filteredStudents" >...</a>
```

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)

Comment: i don't understand what should be my filtername in my code? 

ng-repeat="student in filteredStudents = (students | filter:model.txtSearch)"

Comment: I tried it but it says $filter is not a function

my code is :

 $scope.filteredStudents = $filter('filter')(model.txtSearch);

Comment: Did you inject filter in your controller?

Comment: Yes, what did I do wrong?

app_ctrl.controller('BrowseController',['$scope','$state', 'studentService', '$localstorage','$filter', 
 function($scope, $state, studentService,$localstorage, $timeout, $filter) {
}

Comment: Can you try rearranging injected variables once. timeout & filter.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers execute before the view is rendered, which is why the controller function $scope is empty when it executes.  You could access the $scope.filteredStudents from within an event handler, such as ngClick:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function() {
      alert ($scope.items);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{name}}
  <div ng-repeat="i in items = ([1,2,3,4] | filter:name )">
    {{i}}
  </div>
  <button ng-click="test()">Hey</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can access $scope.filteredStudents by using $timeout:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
     $timeout(function() {
         // $scope.filteredStudents is accessible here...
         alert($scope.filteredStudents);
     });
});
```

This works because the $timeout hander executes after the view is rendered. The javascript enclosure allows the $timeout handler to execute, and still access the controller's function context.