# What is the best practice for using AngularJS filters in a controller/service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've seen both of the following methods to use a filter in a controller/service:

1. `$filter('myFilter')('myStuffToFilter', myFilterArgument)`
2. `myFilterFilter('myStuffToFilter', myFilterArgument)`

They work equally well. Which method constitutes best practice?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a ground-breaking issue, I believe there is a difference and it's worth sharing (as did pkozlowski.opensource in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller#answer-14303362) to a related question). Option 2 is better for the following reasons:

- Cleaner syntax: It's a little cleaner, more straight forward and avoids the sequential parentheses syntax which is less common.
- Provided solution: The myFilterFilter object is not available for code injection by accident. The AngularJS creates these <*filtername*>Filter objects for all filters (pre-defined and custom) and makes them available to the injector.
- Documented solution: The AngularJS documentation recommends this solution in their documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#using-filters-in-controllers-services-and-directives).