# Angular: what is filterFilter

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular and i am bit familiar with `filter` word but what is `filterFilter` word and usage in angular. just come across a code below from this url https://stackoverflow.com/a/22704140/6188148.

### see the code

```
angular.module('FilterInControllerModule', []).
    controller('FilterController', ['filterFilter', function(filterFilter) {
      this.array = [
        {name: 'Tobias'},
        {name: 'Jeff'},
        {name: 'Brian'},
        {name: 'Igor'},
        {name: 'James'},
        {name: 'Brad'}
      ];
      this.filteredArray = filterFilter(this.array, {name:'Igor'});
    }]);
```

just tell me what is `filterFilter` ? is it any built-in filter ?

Comment: It can be a injectable service.

Comment: In this code, it's probably redundant to filter it in the controller unless you're using it multiple times in the View .

Answer (score 9):

Every filter can be injected as a service, whose name is `<theNameOfTheFilter>Filter`.

So, for example, if you want to use the `uppercase` filter from a controller (for example), you can do

```
module.controller('MyController', function($scope, uppercaseFilter) {
    $scope.foo = uppercaseFilter('hello');
});
```

Your code does the same thing, with [the `filter` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: This is correct. You can see a sample here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Note that this is alternate syntax for the syntax given in the correct answer `$filter('uppercase')`.

Answer (score 3):

Angular filter names just have to end with `Filter` in order to be a valid filter.