# How to dynamically apply custom filters in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I know that in angular, to apply a custom filter with ng-repeat will look something like this:

```
ng-repeat="request in allRequests | allRequests"
```

But I've got a couple of different filters. eg.

```
 allFutureRequests, allPastRequests, myPastRequests, group1FutureRequests
```

and I was hoping to swap out the 'allRequests' filter and replace it with any of the other filters dynamically, depending on what what some buttons the user clicks on.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: An initial (Naive) implementation would be to declare the `ng-repeat` several times with an `ng-if` that displays the appropriate one depending on the selected radio button. A better one would be making a function that encompasses all of your filters and using the `ng-model` value for the filters button in an `if else` block, then using the appropriate filter depending on the value. I am not sure if what you want is possible, but if not the latter option would be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way would be to just do this within the controller. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller) sums it up quite nicely.

It works in the format of `$filter('filtername')(argument)`

If you want to add a filter to something on button click, do something like this:

```
$scope.onBtnClick = function(index) {
    $scope.allRequests[index] = $filter('allFutureRequests')($scope.allRequests[index]);
}
```

And you can call that from a click such as this:

```
<button ng-repeat="request in allRequests | allRequests" ng-click="onBtnClick($index)">
```

The above simply just passes the index of that `allRequests` array/object to the function. The function  will then apply that filter to that specific index within it.

Also, don't forget to inject `$filter` into your controller.

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/zilions/pen/MydpKV)

Comment: Hi, the working Example doesn't really work. wrong link perhaps? Otherwise, I think I understand what to do. Thanks a lot! One note though for anyone else reading. $index may not work as expected if the order of the items are sorted in any other way.

Comment: @Synia - Yes wrong link sorry. Have updated it to the working link. Check it out. Let me know if you have any questions. `track by` is probably optional, although usually recommended. Try using a unique identifier instead such as an ID or GUID. I use `track by` often to speed up the performance of my app.