# AngularJS: Get dynamic array from filter then use it into a forEach method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have the following table based in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/oXg2oky1QNb8Yqd7h8Wt?p=preview) **(try to use the 'search' input)**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="product in filteredArray=(products | filter:findProducts)">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the *filteredArray* array is dynamic because this array will list objects based on the filter result and what I need to do is get this *filteredArray* array in the controller into a *forEach* method.

**Controller**

```
app.controller("controllerApp", function($scope){

  $scope.products = [
    {id:1, name: "product AAA", price: 12},
    {id:2, name: "product AAB", price: 21},
    {id:3, name: "product ABB", price: 32},
    {id:4, name: "product ABC", price: 45},
    {id:5, name: "product ACC", price: 34},
    {id:6, name: "product ACA", price: 63},
    {id:7, name: "product ACB", price: 47},
    {id:8, name: "product BBA", price: 87},
    {id:9, name: "product BBB", price: 59},
    {id:10, name: "product BBC", price: 43},
    {id:11, name: "product CCA", price: 76},
    {id:12, name: "product CCB", price: 44}
  ];

  // I can't get the 'filteredArray' from the view.
  angular.forEach(filteredArray, function(value, key){
    console.log("object from filtered array: "+value)
  })
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you should `$watch` for `findProducts` which is modified by `ng-model`. In the `$watch` handler you can update `filteredArray`. In the code that you wrote with `forEach` state will only run once on the controller initialization, and that's not what you want.

Comment: btw, in the controller you can inject `$filter` service and use it instead of implementing your own filter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$scope.$watch` to filter your products in your controller based on user input. You'll then have access to that filtered dataset to perform your `.forEach` loop.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller) on how to use a filter in your controller. And the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) on how to use the built-in filter named 'filter.

```
app.controller("controllerApp", function($scope, $filter){
{
    var products = [...];
    $scope.filteredProducts = products;

    $scope.$watch('findProducts', function(newVal) {
        $scope.filteredProducts = $filter('filter')(products, newVal);

        angular.forEach($scope.filteredProducts, function(value, key){
            console.log("object from filtered array: "+value)
        });
    });
}
```

Then use the `filteredProducts` in your template

```
<input type="text" name="findProducts" data-ng-model="findProducts" placeholder="search" />

<tr data-ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts">
```