# Select an object from an array based on a property value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects. Each object has multiple properties such as 'activityType'. I'm trying to assign that object to $scope.selectedActivity based on the $scope.activityType value that is already assigned. I've tried to use $filter but I'm not sure how to code the expression properly.

This is my code:

```
$scope.selectedActivity = $filter('filter')($scope.activityTypes, $scope.activityTypes.activityType == $scope.activityType);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a filter in a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Give an object for comparision and set to strict (true). Read [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for more informations.

```
$scope.selectedActivity = $filter ('filter')($scope.activityTypes, { 'activityType': $scope.activityType }, true);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it returns all elements which match the criteria in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, asked my question to quickly.

This is how I did it

```
$scope.selectedActivity = $filter('filter')($scope.activityTypes, { activityType: $scope.activityType} );
```